# limit event to direct messages Discord.Py

Tags: discord, bots, discord.py

I am looking to make this command only work in direct messages, its the start of my anti dm advertising bot. I don't want it to check-in servers (which it has been doing) I just need it when it gets direct messaged on discord.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
        if message.content.find("discord.gg") != -1:
                header_payload = {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if message.guild:
    return
```

this will ignore messages from a guild.